# Ед. или мн.число?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Здравствуйте!

Скажите, в каком числе необходимо применить слова "должность" и "сторож"? По контексту - двое человек работали сторожами.

"Они были трудоустроены на должности (или ДОЛЖНОСТЬ) сторожа (или СТОРОЖЕЙ) по совместительству".

Спасибо)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

А в таком случае:

"Она устроила их на 0,5 ставки сторожА (стороЖЕЙ)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ох уж этот канцелярит...
Ведь ясно же любому здравомыслящему, что слово "должность" здесь просто лишнее.
Но если уж из десятка зол выбирать меньшее, то "**на должностях сторожей**".
В остальных случаях возникают обоснованные подозрения в понимании смысла. Типа тех, что они моги работать на одной должности (на полставки, скажем) или у одного сторожа несколько должностей...

"Куда" (на должность) можно послать. А трудоустроить всё-таки - "где" (на должности). Хотя, боюсь, ни один кадровик меня не поймёт.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

А в таком случае:

"Она устроила их на 0,5 ставки сторожА (стороЖЕЙ)"?

Comment: Боюсь, что если требуется юридическая точность (и по контексту не следует иное), то только так: *Она устроила каждого на 0,5 ставки сторожа*. Будете смеяться, но и случай "устройства" двух лиц на одну "полуставку" вполне реален. Так что лучше соломки подстелить.